# Teaching myself HTML/CSS in coursera. I'm stuck

Tags: html, css

I added a picture to describe my problem:

[image: Error]

IN the picture you'll see my HTML code and what the auto grade says I'm doing wrong, but the problem Is that i still have 5 "div" tags in the "body". I don't get it.

In the picture below you'll see what the coursera course wants me to do step by step. Help please:

[image: Assignment]

I added the "div" tags in "body", I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is that the grading system is searching for divs that are directly inside the body tag. The way you have declared them is called nesting, you have basically nested all your divs inside one div: the first div. As only first div is inside the body tag and the rest of divs are inside the div tag, the grading system is not able to find them. You can modify your code so that your divs are in the body tag. Here's a sample for you

```
<body>
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
</body>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It helped, that was the problem exactly, nesting while i shouldn't. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably , you've understood the question incorrectly. From my understanding, you need to have 5 `<div>` tags on top level (i.e. not nested).

Rough e.g.:

```html
<body>
    <div>blah 1</div>
    <div>blah 2</div>
    <div>blah 3</div>
    <div>blah 4</div>
    <div>blah 5</div>
</body>
```

Note: I'm purposefully not giving you exact answer to your assignment, above hint will help you move forward.

Comment: You're correct, i misunderstood and nested when i shouldnt. It helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is you have added nested divs like

```
<div>
   content
<div>
   content
</div>
</div>
```

But they are asking for 5 seperate divs. so you have to close each div before starting the next one.
Like

```
<div> content 1 </div>
<div> content 2 </div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: That's correct, i misinterpreted the assignment, i appreciate the help!